# Django ORM multiple tables query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I trying to make some queries in Django ORM (migration from SQL). My models looks like this

```
class Iv2(models.Model):
    s_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    l_eid = models.CharField(max_length=265)
    t_id = models.CharField(max_length=265,unique=True)

class Sv2(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    s_id = models.OneToOneField(Iv2, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    gdd = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)


class Ev2(models.Model):

    id = models.OneToOneField(Iv2, to_field='l_eid', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    s_id = models.ForeignKey(Iv2, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    car = models.CharField(max_length=265)
```

I want to write a query, given `t_id`(some real search value). I want to get the corresponding `Sv2.gdd` and `Ev2.car`

I'm thinking to get `s_id` and `l_eid` with the `t_id`. And when I get `s_id`. I can query `Sv2` and with `l_eid` I can query `Ev2`.

Is it possible to achieve everything with one ORM query ? can `prefetch/select_related` work here?

Answer (score 0):

"Given t_id of Iv2 get Sv2.gdd and Ev2.car"

First get the Sv2 instance by filtering its 1:1 relation by the
real search value `t_id`:

```
sv2 = Sv2.objects.filter(s_id__t_id=t_id).first()
sv2.gdd
```

Now you have 2 options to get Ev2.car

1. Add related name in Ev2 (more on related_name [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) )
   Assuming your `related_name` is `ev2` you can do:
   `sv2.ev2.car`
2. Use the default django related_name `modelname__set`
   `sv2.ev2_set`